# Regexp in Perl/TCL

Tags: regex, perl, tcl

I am having a string and want to get some part of it. Suppose I am having a string say "set aid ODU4-4-3". I want to take only ODU from it. Whereas the pattern of string is not fixed. IT may some like ODU,ODU4,ODUX. I am not getting how to fetch this

```
$aid = "ODU4-9-1";
$aid =~ /(\w)+\d*-\d-\d/;
print " value is $1"
```

Output

```
value is ODU4
```

I need the value to be ODU only whereas the string pattern may  change. It may be ODU-4-3 only or can go ODU4-4-3.

Comment: What range of values can ODU take?

Comment: patterns are like ODU-9-1, STS-9-1, STS3C-9-1, ODU4-9-1. Issue is ODU may be ODU or some number may be attached to it based on requirement.

Comment: Nitesh, it would be nice if you mention all the cases of ODU.

Comment: What result do you want for 'STS3C-9-1'?

Comment: I am writting a procedure. aid pattern will be like say abc-9-1, abc1-9-1, anything3-9-1. I want to take only alphabetical part of first number. May be i got the answer. I can use [a-zA-Z]. Thanks

Comment: @scroog: for STS3C i need STS

Comment: The issue with the regex you show in the question is that `\w` *includes* digits, so the leading `\w+` is too greedy for your purposes -- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Character-Classes-and-other-Special-Escapes and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#POSIX-Character-Classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version of @M42 's answer that returns all matches:

```
my @allmatches = $aid =~ /([A-Z]{3}).*?\-\d\-\d/;
```

Comment: again ODU is not fixed. It may go upto any numbner of alphabets followed by number or none.

Comment: The question is a string is there like the pattern i described. I want to take only the alphabets in first pattern

Comment: This will not match ` STS3C-9-1`

Comment: What should the result be for this one?

Answer (score 3):

and the Tcl:

```
if {[regexp {^[[:alpha:]]+} $string letters]} {
    puts $letters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$aid =~ /([A-Z]{3}).*?-\d-\d/;
```

for any length more than 0 and case insensitive, use

```
$aid =~ /([a-zA-Z]+).*?-\d-\d/;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only alphabets in **odu** then this should do the trick

```
$aid =~ /([[:alpha:]]+)/;
```

Comment: great. but how it work. Will this fetch all the aplhabets in the string or we can use this as /([:alpha:]).*-\d-\d/

Comment: check **man grep** and search for **alpha** for more explanation on character classes. If you aren't interested in details after ODU, then this should do **/([[:alpha:]]+).*/**